# inserting all the data from multiple list-boxes to a table in the database C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert all the data from 3 list-boxes to a table in the database  i don't know if i'm doing well , this is the code i used

```
private void Order()
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString1))
            {
                String query = "INSERT INTO Tbl_order (OrderName,Quantity,Price,Serves_way,Date) VALUES (@OrderName,@Quantity, @Price,'"+servers+"','" + time1.ToString(format1)+"' )";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < lst_OrderName.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string OrderName = lst_OrderName.GetItemText(lst_OrderName.GetSelected(i));

                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderName", lst_OrderName.GetItemText(lst_OrderName.GetSelected(i)));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", lst_QTY.GetItemText(lst_QTY.GetSelected(i)));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", lst_Price2.GetItemText(lst_Price2.GetSelected(i)));

                        command.Parameters.Add("@OrderName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                        command.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int);
                        command.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Money);

                        command.Parameters.Add("@OrderName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = OrderName;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(lst_QTY.GetSelected(i));
                        command.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Convert.ToDouble(lst_Price2.GetSelected(i));

                    }

                    // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderName", lst_OrderName.GetItemText(lst_OrderName.SelectedItem));
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", lst_QTY.GetItemText(lst_QTY.SelectedItem));
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", lst_Price2.GetItemText(lst_Price2.SelectedItem));

                    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

                    // Check Error
                    if (result < 0)
                        Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into Database!");
                }
            }
        }
```

and i have a problem which is says

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The variable name '@OrderName' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
```

this is the pic of the three list-boxes [![enter image description here][1]][1]

What is wrong in code what did i miss?

I want the data to be inserted in the database for each row like how does it look like in the pic .

Comment: At this point the question is changing significantly from what was originally asked and answered.  The original problem has been solved.  This new problem looks like it should be a new question.  In that question, specifically identify the values you see in the debugger that are being assigned to the parameters and note where the problem is being observed.

Comment: thank you so much , and sorry ^^ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to re-add the same parameters multiple times in a loop before ever executing the query.  Even in a single iteration of the loop, you try to add every parameter *three times*.  The error is telling you that you can only add the same parameter once.

Move the entire lifespan of the query to inside the loop.  Something like this:

```
connection.Open();
for (int i = 0; i < lst_OrderName.Items.Count; i++)
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@OrderName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = OrderName;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(lst_QTY.GetSelected(i));
        command.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Convert.ToDouble(lst_Price2.GetSelected(i));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

This would also be a good time to learn about using transactions with a database.  That way you can wrap all of these inserts in a single transaction and commit or rollback as needed.

Comment: Thank you , I've tried your code  but still the same problem

Comment: @MaxThunder: Can you update the question to show the new code?

Comment: @MaxThunder: Your updated code in the question doesn't try what this answer suggests.  It's still not working because you didn't fix it as instructed.

Comment: this what i got in the database